# Where can I find class 3 gimballed beam lasers?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I've been to lots of high tech, high population systems looking for 3 gimballed beam lasers. Where can I find them in Empire space (without a permit, as my Empire ascension is bugged at the moment)?

Comment: Personally, I'd look at a couple of Li-Yong Rui's large population, high tech control systems. Ships and outfitting are 10–15% discounted, and it seems like there might be a selection bonus, too. My last new ship purchase I bought a hauler, stuck a big fsd and fuel scoop in it, traveled to a system of his, sold the hauler, bought the ship I was after, and only had to visit one other of his systems to complete my outfitting as planned, before returning to my home base.

Comment: @CmdrFreiheit cheers, I did buy my Vulture in one of those systems, but I haven't come across any C3 G beams there or on the trek back (though I did cart some rares with me to help pay when I do find 'em).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find class 3 gimballed multi-cannon?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233534/where-can-i-find-class-3-gimballed-multi-cannon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I found out for myself: you need to restrict systems to high-tech/military very high population systems only, and then check out lots of them.

In Aisline Duval's territory the only system that stocks them appears to be Tietjen Ring in Murato.