# Where can I find class 3 gimballed multi-cannon?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I've been to lots of high tech, high population systems looking for 3 gimballed multi-cannon. Where can I find them in Empire space (without a permit, as my Empire ascension is bugged at the moment)? Do they exist? If not do we have any confirmation from the devs that they're not supposed to (i.e. they aren't just really rare).

Comment: I believe these do exist now in Engineers 2.1

Answer (score 5):

There are no class 3 (large) multi-cannons, railguns, missile racks, torpedo pylons, mine launchers, or mining lasers.

I believe that's because a class 3 multi-cannon would be too powerful and would unbalance things. Same with some of the other weapons lacking a class 3 variant. (Though some might lack a class 3 variant because it seemed unlikely to be useful).

For class 4 (huge), there are only cannon and plasma accelerator.

Comment: Cheers (+1) for the ans do we have any actual confirmation of that? Especially on the weapon balancing, as there are things like class 3 beam lasers that are at a similar level, and weapons like missiles that seem to have started overpowered, been nerfed to uselessness and then just left.

Comment: I can't find confirmation of the reasons for a C3 MC to have been left out or dropped, but here's something from one of the game designers that hints at it (in a discussion about maybe creating a C3 weapons between cannon and multicannon): https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php?t=130531&p=2000151&viewfull=1#post2000151

Comment: However, the large Beam has a high thermal load and draws a lot of power. If you put a pair of large beams on a Vulture (with best power plant and distributor) it won't be able to sustain fire for long, and it will greatly limit your ability to equip and use other power-hungry things (like high rated thrusters, high rated shields, shield cells, shield boosters, etc). Since in class 2, the MC has 1/4 the thermal load of the beam and about half the power, a pair of class 3 MCs would probably be *just too awesome*.